# expected ';' at end of declaration /vector /c++

Tags: c++, vector

When I try to initialize a `vector` of `int`s, I always get this error:

> expected ';' at end of declaration

I used the original code from "C++ Primer":

```
vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

and

```
$ g++ -o test test.cpp
```

I think this is a silly question to ask, but I am sure that there is a `;`. I cannot manage to find an answer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`g++` assumes C++03 by default, and the syntax you're trying to use came in C++11. Change the compilation line to:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
```

Or, as I'd personally prefer:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c++1y -o test test.cpp
```

`:)`

*Note*: whether you'd use `c++0x`, `c++11`, or `c++1y` (and possibly `c++14`) depends mostly on the compiler version, as those were introduced in succesion.

Answer (score 7):

Your compiler by default does not support *brace initialisation*; this was added in C++11.

There's probably a command line argument you can use in your compiler, something along the lines of

`-std=c++11`

Answer (score 1):

Open VS Code settings
search "executor map"
Under "Code-runner: Executor Map" -> click on "Edit in setting.json"
in "code-runner.executorMap"
replace
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
with
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++14 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"

Answer (score 0):

I think u use code runner for build and start .cpp. U must go in setting this extension and change 'Executor Map'. Add for cpp: -std=c++17 -stdlib=li