# Why I cannot initialize variables with curly braces in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++

I don't know why Visual Studio Code and g++ expect a semicolon after a curly braces initialization of a variable. The program is below.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int i{0}; // Semi colon expected here??
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924050/expected-at-end-of-declaration-vector-c) may be useful to you, good luck!

Comment: Either update your GCC installation or add `-std=c++11` to your compiler option

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of code or error messages. You can easily copy-paste them into the question. Images are not accessible to everyone and are not searchable.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Good point. Will keep in mind these issues. Merci.

Answer (score -1):

```
int a = 0;

int a = {0};

int a[2] = {0,1};
```