# How to instantiate variables using brackets on visual studio code?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, g++

Following up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924050/expected-at-end-of-declaration-vector-c), I understand that g++ uses c++03 syntax by default, however how do I go about changing this to c++11 on VSC?

My best guess is that I change my task.json file, but how exactly?

Tasks.json file:

```
 // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/t:build",
                // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm also using VSC on Mac.

Comment: Where did you find this `tasks.json`? Looks like something tailored to MSVC, with the compiler name being replaced with `clang++`. (Why do you mention GCC, if you use Clang?)

Comment: Intellisense is set in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file. You probably want to read the macOS VSCode documentation that explains the 3 files and the settings you need to make: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: OLD versions of g++ default to C++03. Newer ones tend to default to C++17. If you need to set a command line option to get C++11, your toolchain is probably 8-10 years old.

Comment: @Sarah The title of your question does not match the body of your question. Please fix that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay I will go back and change it.  I'm new to all of this so I'm just trying to figure everything out.

Comment: @drescherjm Ok thank you. I will go back and read it